# Constructor not defined: [batchclass].<Constructor>(String)

Tags: trigger, unit-test

Hi i have faced a error writing test Class for batch apex class.

```
global class batchclass implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    global final String Query;
    global batchclass(){} 

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator('Select id, name, Active__c , start_date__c, end_date__c  from Example__c');
    }


    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Example__c> scope){
        for(batchclass s : scope){

        if(s.start_date__c <= system.now() && s.Active__c == true){
            s.put('Active__c',false);

        else if(s.end_date__c < system.now() && s.Active__c == false){
            s.put('Active__c',true); }
        }
        update scope;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

I have wrtitten test class like this ..

```
@isTest
public class Test_batchclass {

    static void testbatchclass(){
        Profile p = [select id from profile where name='System Administrator'];
        // create a user to run the test as
        User u = new User(alias = 'usertest1', email='usertest4@noemail.com',
        emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
        localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id, country='United States',
        timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='usertest4@noemail.com');
        insert u;
        Example__c ex=new Out_Of_Office__c();
        ex.Name='Test';
        ex.Active__c=True;
        ex.Start_Date__c=date.parse('01/06/2015');
        ex.End_Date__c=date.parse('17/06/2015');

        insert ex;

        String query='Select id, name, Active__c , start_date__c, end_date__c  from Example__c';
        batchclass globaltest=new GlobalOutOfOfc_Batch(query);
        Database.executeBatch(batchclass);
    }

}
```

Comment: n.b. global modifier not required for batch classes unless doing managed package; `public` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Change line

```
 batchclass globaltest=new GlobalOutOfOfc_Batch(query);
```

to

```
batchclass globaltest=new batchclass();
```

Also, the class constructor `new GlobalOutOfOfc_Batch(query);` doesn't make sense. It has nothing to do with `query` argument because `batchclass` has hardcoded query.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Ashwani's answer, best practice would be to add to your test class:

```
Test.startTest();
Database.executeBatch(batchclass);
Test.stopTest();

// soql query to fetch Example__c sobjects
system.assert(...) // verify updates done as expected
```